# Function / algorithm to return fixed value for input range

Tags: algorithm, bluetooth

I want to implement an algorithm / function (a kind of license algorithm), let's call it F1, which returns a fixed key for a full range of input values, say mac addresses.
And then implement the inverse function (say F2), which should return true if the 2 inputs are:
- The previously generated key from F1
- A valid input mac address that belongs to the address range provided previously to F1

To be more specific about why I want to do:
I'm implementing a SW code for BT (Bluetooth) platforms (chips / modules) that should work only on a specific range of BT mac addresses. 
The user should provide us with a range of BT addresses (i.e. start address - end address), then using F1 we should provide him with a license key (with a fixed value for all his BT addresses).

Then during MP (mass production) of the BT modules, the module manufacturer shall store this key in the EEPROM on the module.

At module power-up, the function F2 should read the value of the key in EEPROM (as input 1), & read the BT mac address of the module (as input 2), then should return true if this address belongs to the BT address range used for generating the key with F1.

- Any ideas?
- Where should I start reading? Any keywords?

Comment: Seems like you want to create a string that stores start-end address mask and possibly encrypt it. Or is that not the case?

Comment: Maybe. I guess one solution is to form a string of start & end address & encrypt it. On the other side, it can be decrypted & check if the own BT address lies within the range or not.

Comment: In this case I guess traditional Hash functions, SHA-1, 2, etc can be used, right?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, let's say you have two different overlapping ranges, R1 and R2, with two different keys provided by your F1 function, K1 and K2. Then, F2 should return true if it reads either K1 or K2 for a MAC address in the overlap, right? In that case, you need F1 as a reverse-encryptable algorithm that takes start&end or start&mask (if approppriate) and turns it into a "passphrase" by a certain key, then F2 will use either the same key or private key to decrypt the stored value, parse the output vs MAC and return if it's inside the range. So, I think one of the solutions is encryption/decryption via asymmethric keys, one you use as private and for encrypting ranges, the other you provide as public (as it'll be stored explicitly somewhere to be used in F2) to your manufacturer to decrypt your encrypted range.